Showing actual numbers in files added, removed or modified in zsh prompt
Begun going down the rabbit hole of modifying zsh prompt to show relevant git information and I did manage to get the colors to change accordingly based on various statuses. That's all well and good but I wanted to know if there's a way to show the actual numbers. eg would be:
~workdirectory (branch-name | ^no. of files added in color green | v no. of files remove in red | <> no. of files modified in color yellow)
or something like that. I'm using vcs_info to get git info.
EDIT:
Figured it out (with the help of Claude). Decided to use and override Prompt Pure as it had faster ways to check dirty state than handcrafting my own
# Custom git status function
prompt_pure_git_status_counts() {
    local staged_files=0
    local modified_files=0
    local deleted_files=0
    local untracked_files=0

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        local file_status=${line:0:2}
        case "$file_status" in
            'A '|'M ') ((staged_files++));;
            ' M'|'MM') ((modified_files++));;
            ' D'|'D ') ((deleted_files++));;
            '??') ((untracked_files++));;
        esac
    done < <(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null)

    local status_string=""
    [[ $staged_files -gt 0 ]] && status_string+="%F{green}+${staged_files}%f "
    [[ $modified_files -gt 0 ]] && status_string+="%F{yellow}~${modified_files}%f "
    [[ $deleted_files -gt 0 ]] && status_string+="%F{red}-${deleted_files}%f "
    [[ $untracked_files -gt 0 ]] && status_string+="%F{cyan}?${untracked_files}%f"

    echo -n " $status_string"
}

# Override Pure's preprompt render function
function prompt_pure_preprompt_render() {
    setopt localoptions noshwordsplit

    # Set color for git branch/dirty status and change color if dirty checking has been delayed.
    local git_color=$prompt_pure_colors[git:branch]
    local git_dirty_color=$prompt_pure_colors[git:dirty]
    [[ -n ${prompt_pure_git_last_dirty_check_timestamp+x} ]] && git_color=$prompt_pure_colors[git:branch:cached]

    # Initialize the preprompt array.
    local -a preprompt_parts

    # Username and machine, if applicable.
    [[ -n $prompt_pure_state[username] ]] && preprompt_parts+=($prompt_pure_state[username])

    # Set the path.
    preprompt_parts+=('%F{${prompt_pure_colors[path]}}%~%f')

    # Git branch and status
    typeset -gA prompt_pure_vcs_info
    if [[ -n $prompt_pure_vcs_info[branch] ]]; then
        local git_status="$(prompt_pure_git_status_counts)"
        preprompt_parts+=("%F{$git_color}${prompt_pure_vcs_info[branch]}%F{$git_dirty_color}${prompt_pure_git_dirty}%f${git_status}")
    fi

    # Git action (for example, merge).
    if [[ -n $prompt_pure_vcs_info[action] ]]; then
        preprompt_parts+=("%F{$prompt_pure_colors[git:action]}$prompt_pure_vcs_info[action]%f")
    fi

    # Git pull/push arrows.
    if [[ -n $prompt_pure_git_arrows ]]; then
        preprompt_parts+=('%F{$prompt_pure_colors[git:arrow]}${prompt_pure_git_arrows}%f')
    fi

    # Git stash symbol (if opted in).
    if [[ -n $prompt_pure_git_stash ]]; then
        preprompt_parts+=('%F{$prompt_pure_colors[git:stash]}${PURE_GIT_STASH_SYMBOL:-≡}%f')
    fi

    # Execution time.
    [[ -n $prompt_pure_cmd_exec_time ]] && preprompt_parts+=('%F{$prompt_pure_colors[execution_time]}${prompt_pure_cmd_exec_time}%f')

    local cleaned_ps1=$PROMPT
    local -H MATCH MBEGIN MEND
    if [[ $PROMPT = *$prompt_newline* ]]; then
        cleaned_ps1=${PROMPT##*${prompt_newline}}
    fi
    unset MATCH MBEGIN MEND

    # Construct the new prompt with a clean preprompt.
    local -ah ps1
    ps1=(
        ${(j. .)preprompt_parts}  # Join parts, space separated.
        $prompt_newline           # Separate preprompt and prompt.
        $cleaned_ps1
    )

    PROMPT="${(j..)ps1}"

    # Expand the prompt for future comparison.
    local expanded_prompt
    expanded_prompt="${(S%%)PROMPT}"

    if [[ $1 == precmd ]]; then
        # Initial newline, for spaciousness.
        print
    elif [[ $prompt_pure_last_prompt != $expanded_prompt ]]; then
        # Redraw the prompt.
        prompt_pure_reset_prompt
    fi

    typeset -g prompt_pure_last_prompt=$expanded_prompt
}

Doing this gets me exactly what I need:


This should be possible with vcs_info hooks, see https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.9/Misc/vcs_info-examples#L177-L198 for an example that does something similar.
